# Javascript callback in JavaFX from within a HTML page (using D3)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

While using the forcelayout, I am trying to call a JavaFX method on selecting a node in D3 (which is in a HTML page). I am not sure what wrong am I doing here

Lets say I use a WebView to render an HTML page which had D3 used to draw a graphs. On selection of one of the nodes (using "dblclick" property of D3), I would like to invoke a method of javaFX

This is how I render the WebView

```
    weMainGraph = wvMainGraph.getEngine();
    weMainGraph.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Worker.State>() {
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Worker.State> p, Worker.State oldState, Worker.State newState) {
                if (newState == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {
                    JSObject win = (JSObject) weMainGraph.executeScript("window");
                    win.setMember("javaObj", new Connector2(Scene2Controller.this));      
                    System.out.println("Scene2Controller.intiateMainGraph(): Called");
                }
            }
        }
    );   

    final URL urlLoadMainGraph = getClass().getResource("MainGraph.html");
    weMainGraph.load(urlLoadMainGraph.toExternalForm());
```

And the MainGraph.html is as follows

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.node {
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.link {
  stroke: #999;
  stroke-opacity: .6;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var width = 640; var height = 300;
// var w = window.innerWidth; var h = window.innerHeight;

var color = d3.scale.category20();

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .charge(-120)
    .linkDistance(100)
    .size([width, height]);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

d3.json("MainGraph.json", function(error, graph) {
  force
      .nodes(graph.nodes)
      .links(graph.links)
      .start();

  var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
      .data(graph.links)
    .enter().append("line")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .style("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); })
      .call(force.drag);


  var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
      .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("r", 5)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); })
      .on("click", click)
      .on("dblclick", doubleclick)
      .call(force.drag);

  node.append("title")
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

  var texts = svg.selectAll("text.label")
                .data(graph.nodes)
                .enter().append("text")
                .attr("class", "label")
                .attr("fill", "black")
                .text(function(d) {  return d.name;  });

    function click(){
            d3.select(this).attr('r', 10).transition()
                .duration(3000)
                // .style("fill","yellow")
                .style("stroke","black")
                .style("stroke-opacity",1);
        }

    function doubleclick(){
        d3.select(this).transition()
            .duration(750)
            .attr("r", 5)
            .style("stroke-opacity",0);
        // javaObj.onclickLeftView();
        javaObj.onselectNode();
    }

    function alertBox() {
        window.alert("Executes");
    }


  force.on("tick", function() {
    link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });

     texts.attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + (d.x+3) + "," + d.y + ")";
    });

    });
});

</script>
```

And the Connector2 is

```
public class Connector2 {
private final Scene2Controller controller ;

public Connector2(Scene2Controller controller) {
    this.controller = controller ;
}

public void onselectNode() {
    try {
        System.out.println("Connector2.onselectNode(): Called");              
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Connector.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }        
}
}
```

Comment: I can't see onclickLeftView() method in your connector?

Comment: Actually, the method to be called is javaobj.onselectNode(). I have edited the code to reflect the changes

Answer (score 0):

I did not investigate your example in detail but while writing a [javafx-d3 wraper](https://github.com/stefaneidelloth/javafx-d3) a similar issue for me was that the action listeners passed to javascript must not be anonymeous classes. After considering this the interaction between javafx and d3 worked out very well for me.